# Distribution of areas of uniform random cuts in a sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, area, spheres

#### TLDR;

What's the probability law of the area of a random cut on a sphere, with the random cut being perpendicular to a fixed segment connecting two antipodal points on the sphere, and sampled uniformly?

#### More precise description and my results

Suppose to have a sphere of radius 1, to choose a segment connecting two antipodal points and to randomly sample (with uniform distribution) a point on this segment. Now draw the 2d plane orthogonal to the segment and passing by the point.

This plan will cut the sphere in two, determining a circle. I would like to find the distribution of the areas of such circles.

Using the [transfer operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_operator), unless I did some trivial algebra  errors, I have showed that called $P(A)$ the random variable of the area of such circle, we have that (the support is $[0, \pi]$), $P(A)$ has a density, and it is

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{(1 - A/\pi)}}.
$$

Since I need this result for a computational problem I would be fine with this, but I wonder it this density is coming from a know probability law. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It is a stretched (by a factor of $\pi$) version of a $\text{Beta}\left(1,\frac12\right)$ distribution

Comment: Brillian! Thank you. If you make it as an answer I'll give you a deserved upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

It is a stretched (by a factor of $\pi$) version of a $\text{Beta}\left(1,\frac12\right)$ distribution

See Wikipedia on the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) for some of the statistics, remembering to scale where necessary

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? ... It seems to me that we have the area of the base of a spherical cap (like in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) picture), so $A=\pi\sin^2\theta$, $\theta\sim\text{Uniform}(0,\pi)$. If so, I think @Nisba's density for $A$ is missing a factor that turns it into a (stretched) $\text{Beta}(1/2,1/2)$ distribution.

Comment: @r.e.s.  Traces of the Bertrand paradox. What seems to be uniformly distributed is the point on a diagonal of the sphere (I think *segment* is used here as line segment rather than circular or spherical segment). So the point halfway from the centre to the surface corresponds to a median area of $\pi\left(1-\frac1{2^2}\right)$.  This is consistent with $\text{Beta}(1,1/2)$ but not with  $\text{Beta}(1/2,1/2)$.